# Perl - chaining method calls

Tags: perl, methods, method-chaining

I have a class and want to chain its methods calls in strict order, but can't figure out how to do it.

```
# Mail.pm

package Mail;

sub new { ... }
sub inbox { ... }
sub folder { ... }
sub count { ... }

1;
```

and later ...

```
use Mail;

my $mail = Mail->new;

# ok
$mail->inbox->count;
$mail->folder('Spam')->count;

# prevent calling inbox() after folder() or vice versa
$mail->inbox->folder('Spam')->count;
$mail->folder('Spam')->inbox->count;
```

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clearly, `folder` should return a `My::Mail::Folder` object which has a count, and no `inbox` method, and `inbox` should return a `My::Mail::Box` object which has a `count` method, but no `folder` method.

On the other hand, I am not sure why `$mail->inbox->folder('Spam')->count;` is problematic.

On the other other hand, why are you attracted to method chaining?

Also, keep in mind that there are a whole bunch of CPAN modules under the `Mail::` namespace including [Mail::Box](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mail::Box), and it might help your sanity in the long run to put things in a namespace that is less likely to be trampled on by a CPAN module you might need.

Comment: @abra:  *"On the other other hand, why are you attracted to method chaining?"* I agree. That is a very Ruby-like approach, and doesn't reveal well what is going on in your code.  The bottom line is that each method must return an object that provides the next method in the chain. For `nwe` that's a given - it will return a `Mail` object that has an `inbox` method (but please call it `My::Mail` or similar as Sinan has said, so as not to clash with existing classes). But `inbox` and `folder` must return something other than another `Mail` object because they represent different things.